# #1064 SQL Error in insert statement with set oparator

Tags: mysql, sql

```
insert into group 
set group_name = 'IBM', 
comapny_name = 'IBM Pvt Ltd', 
group_details = 'Hyderabad, Vizag, Bengalore'
```

Error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group set group_name = 'IBM' , comapny_name = 'IBM Pvt Ltd' , group_details = 'H' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the table name group it with ` :

Ex :

```
insert into `group`
set group_name = 'IBM', 
comapny_name = 'IBM Pvt Ltd', 
group_details = 'Hyderabad, Vizag, Bengalore'
```